# How can I build my own checks for spring cloud contract DSL, without regex

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud-contract

Example json:

```
{ id: 50,
  dateTime: "2017-03-09T10:26: }
```

Instead of writing a regex to accept any number for the id, I want to check if it is parseable to `Integer`.

For the dateTime I could write something like `'([0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])'` (from RegexPatterns class) but I just want to check that its parseable to `LocalDateTime`.

#### Solution from Marcin's answer:

In the contract:

```
id: $(consumer(50), producer(execute('isInteger($it+"")'))),
dateTime: $(consumer('2017-03-09T10:26'), producer(execute('isLocalDate($it)'))),
```

In the BaseClass:

```
public void isLocalDate(String date) {
    boolean parseAble = false;
    try {
        LocalDateTime.parse(date);
        parseAble = true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    }
    assertThat(parseAble).isEqualTo(true);
}

public void isInteger(String value) {
    boolean parseAble = false;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(value);
        parseAble = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
    assertThat(parseAble).isEqualTo(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `execute` method and create your own method to parse the value. You can also provide your own customizations and write your own methods. Check this http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.3.RELEASE/#_executing_custom_methods_on_server_side and this http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.3.RELEASE/#_extending_the_dsl respectively for more information

Comment: Alright that works! Thanks. But it feels like a workaround, passing the method as a String.

Comment: No - it's not a workaround. Remember that the same contract is used on the consumer side so we want the DSL to compile there. Also the provided method has to be present at runtime so it doesn't matter if you use a closure, dynamic execution or string.